# The size of the QR image doesn't change regardless of using the size property of QRImage widget which comes from the qr_flutter package

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm using the "qr_flutter" package for generating the QR code. Within the package, there's a widget named QRImage() which has certain properties. As per requirement, the QR image needs to be changed whenever the user opts for a specific size. I tried using the code below. However, the actual QR image size doesn't change, instead the size extended with blank space at the bottom.

Here is the snippet :

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: Center(
                  child: RepaintBoundary(
                    key: globalKey,
                    child: Expanded(
                      child: QrImage(
                        //plce where the QR Image will be shown
                        data: qrData,
                        size: 1000.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),]))),
```

Below is the QR code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-O9cuCkZ6hHNDz6IU_VuaSlzli5riDME/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

The size of the actual QR image also depends on the data that you have supplied. So if the data is long enough, the QR image also adjusts to the length of the data.

Comment: I want to set a specific size for the QR Image when a user opts any of the provided option using the size property. How can i achieve this?

Comment: If your goal is to just display the QRImage() then you can make the size property dynamic by making the user input their choice of size. However, if you want to paint the QR image and adjust the size, you can do that by the QRPainter and adjust the size. Ex: final painter = QRPainter.withQr(...)  In the painter variable, there's this property called toImageData where you can adjust the size. Ex: painter.toImageData(320);

Comment: Yes @Dean i'm just tying to display the QRImage() and make the size property dynamic by change as per the user input and their choice of size, while doing so the size isn't getting changed.

Comment: Have you tried removing the crossAxisAlignment or mainAxisAlignment? Or instead of putting the size on QRImage(), put it on the Container() inside the children widget?